# Can't install modules for python3

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon ec2 (red-hat based), recently I've installed python3 (also have python 2.7 as default) and used

```
$ curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
$ sudo python3.2 get-pip.py
```

to install pip3.

`pip3` is working, but `sudo pip3` throws `sudo: pip3: command not found`

**[*Update]**

I have deleted instace (ec2 amazon) and ran a new one, then installed python3 with "sudo yum install python3" and "get-pip.py" for pip3:

```
pip3 --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
```

But I can't install modules ("cherrypy" etc.) for python3. And "sudo pip3" still not working.
"python3 cherrypyExample.py" gives me an error "ImportError: No module named 'cherrypy'"

Comment: Why can't you use `sudo pip3`?

Comment: What is the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: Why not use `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`? I believe it's available via the default PPAs.

Comment: If `pip3` works, I don't see why `sudo pip3` wouldn't work

Comment: Also, `pip` is preinstalled on Python3.4+ and 2.7.9+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I've found solution:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install cherrypy
```

Comment: do you know what does -m flag means in the above command?